# Using PHP and Swift to serve image to iOS App

Tags: php, swift, swift3, jpeg

I am attempting to serve an image to an iOS application written in Swift 3. I am able to load the image directly from it's URL however, because there is no HTTPS for the image, I am forced to write a wrapper in PHP that can ingest the image and reserve it via HTTPS. I am using CakePHP to serve the image which is working fine however, the iOS application isn't displaying the image. The image is being retrieved but it does not show up in the UIImageView. Any help is appreciated.

**Swift 3**

```
let mugshotParams: [String:Any] = [
    "action":"632",
    "params":[
        "offender_id":"\(self.delegate.predators[index].id)"
    ]
]

do {
    let mugshotObject = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: mugshotParams, options:[])
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: delegate.urlMobile! as String)!, cachePolicy:NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 30)

    request.httpBody = mugshotObject
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error in
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            infoWindow.imageMugshot.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            infoWindow.imageMugshot.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        }
    })

    task.resume()
} catch {

}
```

**CakePHP**

```
private function getPredatorMugshot() {
    $image = file_get_contents('http://domain.com/predator/image.jpg');

    $this->response->type('jpg');
    $this->response->body($image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would resolve this with your `App Transport Security Settings` in your `App-Info.plist`

Here is the XML you add to this file.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>domainservingimages.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Comment: The problem is beginning January 1st, Apple will not accept any application that have exceptions to the App Transport Security or that set the App Transport Security to false/no, so this will not work.